# Net Core Cors and Angular application on IIS

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cors

I'm having some troubles setting up the correct Cors settings on my application.
`NetCore` application with `Angular6` hosted on `IIS`, the `angular` app is outside the `.Net` project and compiled and inserted inside the `wwwroot` when publishing.

Now the problem is that when I'm coding the `angular` part, I'd like to call directly the release server to test some functionality. 
I tried any kind of approach to have this work out but it seems like I'm always hitting a problem with the Cors setup but only for the `POST` calls, `GET` works fine. So here is my startup code:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerManager, LoggerManager>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDbContext, MongoDbContext>();
    services.AddSingleton<IIdGenerator, IdGenerator>();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme(){In = "header",Description = "Please enter JWT with Bearer into field", Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey"});
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            {"Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>()}
        });
    });
    services.AddCustomRepositories();
    services.AddCustomServices();
    services.AddJwtService();

    //Add cors
    services.AddCors();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
    });
    services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("SystemSettings"));
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod());

    app.UseDefaultFiles();

    // this will serve js, css, images etc.
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && 
            !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/") &&
            !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/swagger"))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            await context.Response.SendFileAsync(
                env.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("wwwroot/index.html")
            );
            return;
        }
        await next();
    });

    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

    app.UseMvc();  

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
    });
}
```

Since I want this enabled only for development purpose I'd like to enable it globally.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Failed to load https://xxx:8080/api/users: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Ok, good - that's what I was expecting. Note the last line: *The response had HTTP status code **500***. This means your server is throwing an exception and *that* is what you should be looking in to.

Comment: I thought that the 500 was given for the Cors problem...

Comment: No, not normally. Check your debugger, logging, etc, to see where an exception is being thrown in your ASP.NET Core project. In current versions of ASP.NET Core, the CORS headers don't get set when an error occurs.

Comment: It seems like I'm having some kind of exception not logged inside the program, I'm trying to debug it now, but I think that it could be the problem for now

Comment: try to enable `stdoutLogEnabled` in web.config to check whether there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set the origin manually

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod());
```

as shown [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XXX/api/users' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Pretty much the same error as before, but with the "AllowAnyOrigin" there should be no need

Comment: try setting the .AllowAllHeaders()

Comment: yeah already did, i just changed the AllowAnyOrigin with the specific one, I tried with this setting: app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());

Comment: try AllowAnyOrigins()

Comment: AllowAnyOrigin is what I used in the main example

Comment: have you checked the preflight (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#preflight-requests)? download fiddler and check if the OPTIONS requests are going out... and remember to clear the cache always

Answer (score 0):

[image: adding cors to startup asp.net core web API]

This's the necessary part to add cors in your web API.

Comment: Please do not share code as image. Please use the [code formatting tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) of StackOverflow